# Regex to capture only 1st occurrence inside parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I have data that looks like this:

```
string = 'composition (irreg.): 13/16 × 2 3/4" (2 × 7 cm); page: 8 3/8 × 6 7/8" (21.3 × 17.4 cm)'
```

I want to write a regex that captures the first occurrence of a string with parentheses containing `cm`. So, in the example above, I want a regex that captures `(2 × 7 cm)`.

So far I have this regex which doesn't quite work:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\(.*?.*cm\).*?')
>>> result = pattern.search(string)
>>> match = result.group(0)
'(irreg.): 13/16 × 2 3/4" (2 × 7 cm); page: 8 3/8 × 6 7/8" (21.3 × 17.4 cm)'
```

What regex can I use to ONLY match `(2 × 7 cm)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.*` to `[()*]` so it won't match across multiple parentheses.

You also don't need `.*?` after the parentheses that you want to match. Since it's non-greedy, it doesn't match anything.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\([^()]*cm\)')
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the section you want to match is always of the format `(n x n cm)`, you can use:

```
'\(\d*\.?\d+ × \d*\.?\d+ cm\)'
```

`\d*\.?\d+` will take care of matching a decimal number. Specifying it like this means that you won't accidentally pick up other brackets in the string (such as the bracket before `irreg`).

Here it is in action:
https://regex101.com/r/tfVrsU/1